# Generate Balanced Batches from Unbalanced Data in tfrecords

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset with 20k positive instances, and 300k negative instances.

I would like to create a tfrecord file for each class, and then shuffle the data and generate batches with balanced classes.